# Get differencing items between a collection and its subgroup

Tags: c#, linq

I got stuck with the following problem.

For example, I have some collection of items

```
    List<int> exampleList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 5, 6, 6 };
```

And some other collection of items that is subgroup of first one

```
    List<int> customSelection = new List<int> { 1, 5, 6, 6, 8 };
```

What I want is to obtain difference between them, e.g. to get a collection containing items`{ 3, 7, 5, 6, 6 }`or in other words some`IEnumerable<int> resultingCollection`that will make`customSelection.Concat(resultingCollection)`to be equivalent to`exampleList`(not looking at items order).

I can't use`.Except()`extension method because it will exclude all items from first collection that are present in second one and that is not what I'm looking for. The only solution I came with is to do the following

```
        // count item occurances in first collection
        var countedItemsInFisrt = exampleList.GroupBy(item => item)
            .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
        // count item occurances in second collection
        var countedItemsInSecond = customSelection.GroupBy(item => item)
            .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());

        List<int> resultingCollection = new List<int>();

        int itemsCountDifference;
        int itemsCountInSecond;
        foreach (var kvp in countedItemsInFisrt)
        {
            // when item count in first collection is grater then in second one we add it to resulting collection
            // "count difference" times
            if (!countedItemsInSecond.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out itemsCountInSecond))
                itemsCountInSecond = 0;
            itemsCountDifference = kvp.Value - itemsCountInSecond;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsCountDifference; i++)
                resultingCollection.Add(kvp.Key);
        }

        var stringResult = resultingCollection.Select(items => items.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(stringResult.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b));
```

And this is just huge bunch of code to perform a selection. And even more I'm worried about performance becase in real case both collections can have thouthands of items.

Can this be done in some better way? Maybe I am missing something about LINQ that can help in my case?

**EDIT:**

The best solution for now is the last algorithm suggested by Ulugbek Umirov. It preserves order in the original collection and it also is significantly faster by 2.5 times than any other algorithm suggested when we have selection of 1/2 of original collection and even faster when selection is lesser. Great thanks to Ulugbek Umirov! I've made it into generic extension method that works with any generic collection:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Subtract<T>(this IEnumerable<T> minuend, IEnumerable<T> subtrahend)
    {
        var diffList = new List<T>(minuend.Count() - subtrahend.Count());
        var diffDict = subtrahend.GroupBy(n => n)
                                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
        minuend.ForeEach(n =>
        {
            int count = 0;
            if (diffDict.TryGetValue(n, out count))
            {
                if (count == 1)
                    diffDict.Remove(n);
                else
                    diffDict[n] = count - 1;
            }
            else
                diffList.Add(n);
        });

        return diffList;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more input/output examples, because I do not understand what you mean saying "difference between them" and why doesn't Except help you.

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi I think what he means is if an item appears twice in the collection and once in the sub-collection, he wants it to appear once in the result, whereas `Except` would remove it altogether

Comment: @BenAaronson is right about what I want to get. Actually I need to divide original collection in two - selected items and not selected items, so in terms of a group theory I need to get difference of original group and it's subgroup. My question is a bit more general because I want to know if it's possible to subtract one collection from another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't group second list.

```
List<int> exampleList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 5, 6, 6 };
List<int> customSelection = new List<int> { 1, 5, 6, 6, 8 };

var diffDic = exampleList.GroupBy(n => n)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
customSelection.ForEach(n =>
{
    if (diffDic.ContainsKey(n))
        diffDic[n]--;
});
var diffList = diffDic.Where(p => p.Value > 0)
                      .SelectMany(p => Enumerable.Repeat(p.Key, p.Value))
                      .ToList();
```

Also the following piece of code may improve the performance:

```
customSelection.ForEach(n =>
{
    int count = 0;
    if (diffDic.TryGetValue(n, out count))
    {
        if (count == 1)
            diffDic.Remove(n);
        else
            diffDic[n] = count - 1;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to preserve the original order of items, you can use the following code:

```
List<int> exampleList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 5, 6, 6 };
List<int> customSelection = new List<int> { 1, 5, 6, 6, 8 };

var diffList = new List<int>(exampleList.Count);
var customSelectionDic = customSelection.GroupBy(n => n)
                                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
exampleList.ForEach(n =>
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (customSelectionDic.TryGetValue(n, out count))
        {
            if (count == 1)
                customSelectionDic.Remove(n);
            else
                customSelectionDic[n] = count - 1;
        }
        else
            diffList.Add(n);
    });

// diffList: { 3, 7, 5, 6, 6 }
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for answers. As I see it's not that simple like one linq querry to do what I want. The thing I missed was Enumerable.Repeat. This answer I like most for beeing short and seeming to have performance of O(n) and also to have a tweak to even more lower processing time. Thanks again.

Comment: Great idea! It's also significantly faster(about 2.5 times), though I modified it a bit to 
var diffList = new List<int>(exampleList.Count - customSelection .Count);
because if the second is subgroup of the first one we can calculate exact size of resulting list.

Comment: @user3598905 I specially made `exampleList.Count`, since it may happen that none of elements of `customSelection` will match elements of `exampleList`. Also `new List(int count)` will throw exception in case of negative `count`.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be the fastest, and will change the original list, but I think this is the shortest way:

```
customSelection.ForEach(x => exampleList.Remove(x));
```

Now *exampleList*  will contain `3,7,5,6,6`

Comment: This is an `O(N*M)` solution. It may not be fast enough for OP's purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is just to remove the items in the first list one at a time from a copy of the second:

```
var exampleList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 5, 6, 6 };
var customSelection = new List<int> {1, 5, 6, 6, 8};

var result = new List<int>(exampleList);

foreach (var item in customSelection)
{
    result.Remove(item);
}
```

However, this isn't very performant because of internal adjustments that must be done every time an item is removed from a list, and you mention that being a concern in the OP. First, test it, and if the performance isn't good enough, then I would use `List.RemoveAll` for this. It takes a predicate, which means that it can include local variables:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var exampleList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 5, 6, 6 };
        var customSelection = new List<int> {1, 5, 6, 6, 8};

        var counts = customSelection.GroupBy(x => x)
                     .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Count());
        var removedCounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        var result = new List<int>(exampleList);

        result.RemoveAll(x => RemovalCheck(counts, removedCounts, x));
    }

    private static bool RemovalCheck(Dictionary<int, int> counts, Dictionary<int, int> removed, int item)
    {
        if (!counts.ContainsKey(item))
            return false;
        if (!removed.ContainsKey(item))
            removed[item] = 0;
        if (removed[item] >= counts[item])
            return false;
        removed[item]++;
        return true;
    }
```

(You could do this all in a lambda rather than defining a separate method, but I don't see any reason to)

Both of these return the desired result.